# is it possible run ARKit application to track facial expression in background in swift?

Tags: swift, arkit

1. I have created the app where you can detect the facial expression of the user using ARKIT2.
2. I am able to print the expression within the app.
3. What I want to achieve is the facial expression of the user even in the background.

I have tried [`background-modes-tutorial-getting-started`](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) this link for background modes.

Answer (score 1):

no you cannot use ARKit in the background. It would use up too much battery for a start.

Always check the supported background modes for what you can and can't do. I've always found [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) to be a good guide but it may not be up to date. You should check the Apple developer documentation

Comment: i am new to ARKit, my requirement was to track facial expression of user while using other application to observe his satisfaction level like happy, sad, neutral..etc, i have done it in same application level, i thought there could be a way to achieve this in background, thanks for sharing your knowledge.